# How to call Cloud Function from Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update some values that I will enter from my Flutter app to FireStore using Cloud Functions.  Here is my code so far:

This is my Cloud function (in JavaScript, `index.js`) to update a document in FireStore:

```
exports.update = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const getNewPercentage = req.body;
const getDocument = admin.firestore().collection('waterpercentage').doc('percentage');

getDocument.get().then((doc) => {
    if(doc.exists) {
        getDocument.update({'percentage': getNewPercentage}).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error: ", err);
            res.send("500");
        })
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error: ", err)
    res.send("500");
});
res.send(200);
```

})

In Flutter, here's what I tried:

```
  Future<void> updateWaterPercentage() async {
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('update');
//final results = await callable.call(<dynamic, int>{'percentage' : percentage.round()});
log("Calling percentage here: ");
log(percentage.round().toString());
dynamic resp = await callable.call(<double, dynamic> {
  percentage : percentage.round(),
});
```

When I call updateWaterPercentage() from a Button in Flutter, the data doesn't get updated in FireStore.  I also tried using:

```
CloudFunctions.instance.call(
                    functionName: "update",
                    parameters: {
                      "percentage": percentage.round(),
                    }
                  );
```

However, even though I imported `'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';` on top, Flutter doesn't recognize `CloudFunctions`.  How can I get the code to call `update` that takes in a parameter to correctly update a value in Firestore?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTPS Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Your Cloud Function code corresponds to an HTTP one (`functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {(...)}`) but the code in your app declares and calls a Callable one (`HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('update');`).

In addition, in your HTTPS Cloud Function code, you send back a response before the asynchronous operation is complete (see the last line `res.send(200);`).

So, to fix the problem:

- You could call the HTTPS Cloud Function from your flutter app with the [`http` package](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data);
- But the best would probably be to adapt your Cloud Function to be a Callable one in order to get the advantages of a Callable, including the use of the [`cloud_functions`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_functions/latest/) package which makes very easy to call the CF from your app. Something along the following lines.

---

```
exports.update = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const getNewPercentage = data.percentage;

    const documentRef = admin.firestore().collection('waterpercentage').doc('percentage');

    return documentRef.get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                return documentRef.update({ 'percentage': getNewPercentage });
            } else {
                throw new Error('Doc does not exist');
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            return { result: "doc updated" };
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error: ", err)
            // See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
        });

});
```

Comment: I somehow get an error in the onCall method you provided that the get request isn't valid.

Comment: Can you give more details? What is the exact error message? Also, see that I've just corrected a mistake in the code.  getDocument => documentRef

Comment: Yes- so when I paste the link of the firestore cloudfunction, and also when I test it on the Google Cloud console, I get the JSON response "error:{message: "Bad request" status: "Invalid_argument"}"

Comment: This is my Firestore document structure: https://imgur.com/a/4U2v3dK

Comment: Where do you « paste the link »? And which link? The Cloud Function URL??

Comment: I sent you a private chat with some more details

Comment: You don't need to use a link (i.e. to call the Cloud Function URL). As you will see in the [FlutterFire doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage), you should call them via the `cloud_functions.dart` package. It is what you do in your question actually! Also, see the [generic doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0) which explains the all Callable Cloud Functions concept.